# RabbitMQ - Is it fine to acknowlege message outside the delivery callback?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm writing a service to communicate with RabbitMQ, using RabbitMQ .NET/C# client, with manual acknowlegement of consumed messages.
All tutorials and examples suggest ACKing messages just before event handler returns:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    // copy or deserialise the payload
                    // and process the message
                    // ...
                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                };

channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer)
```

Is it OK to call BasicAck later, when event handler returns and possibly several more messages received?

In my case processing message means to send it outside and wait for result of processing and then ACK or NACK the message depending on result. Tasks are to be processed in parallel and possibly not in same order.  Outside service or this app may crash or restart, so in this case we need to requeue data and process again.

So, the question is - is this scheme valid, in terms of syncronization and RabbitMQ inner logic?

```
// Setup RabbitMQ consumer:
// ...
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    // send data far away for processing
    MyDispatcher.SendTask(ea.DeliveryTag, body);
};
channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer)
// ...
// callback when task was(or was not) processed by Dispatcher
Dispatcher_OnTaskReply(ulong deliveryTag, bool ack)
{
    if(ack) channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag, false) // processed OK
    else channel.BasicNAck(deliveryTag, false, true) // failed, process again
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm one of the primary maintainers of the .NET client. I think this should be fine ... have you tried it? If it doesn't work start a discussion here - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions

Comment: Hello, @Luke, thanks for reply. I made this, it worked fine at test environment, but some strange problems came up at production, so I'm digging into.